# Disabling auto logout when user is inactive in ASP .NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I tried to parse this code into IdentityHostingStartup.cs:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            });
```

But it didn't work. User gets logout after 10-20 minutes if he is inactive. Redirection to Login Page doesn't work too.
Startup.cs doesn't use services so I can't implement this code on this class.
Also i checked cookie life time and the time is correct. But I can't understand how to solve this problems with maximizing time from logout and set redirection to Login page...
[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRlX.jpg)

Hope you can help me, thanks.
All my IdentityHostingStartup code:

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<PerceptionDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PerceptionContextConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<PerceptionUser>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PerceptionDbContext>();
            
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? You can try to set timespan to a very large number or check this [discussion](https://forums.asp.net/t/1930293.aspx?Remove+automatic+session+expire)

Comment: @Tisa the problem is I can't increase TimeSpan Cookie Timeout. As You can see I tried to set it FromDays(1), but it doesn't matter how much time do I set. After ~10 min user is logging out anyway

Comment: it was long time ago but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent a long time trying to figure out what was going on. In the end I found this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12166

Adding the following line in my `Startup.cs` seems to have fixed it for me:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
```